# Get data from tooltip with Python

Tags: python, tooltip, extract

If I use an application on windows and I hover mouse over an icon appear a little yellow rectangle. (tooltip maybe) How can I extract data from that?

Comment: So you want type, size, date-modified of any file passed only ?

Comment: No, I don't want to handle files, I want to hande an application. I want to automatize a process and for this I need the text from appearing tooltip when I move the mouse.